# Serialize a list os questions and return as a JSON

Tags: python, django, list, serialization

I'm trying to serialize a list of objects, but I get an erro,

How can I serialize this list of objects? Thanks

```
       ids = request.data.__getitem__("ids")
       questions_array = []
       for id in ids:
           questions = Question.objects.filter(pk=id)
           questions_array.append(questions)

       serializer = QuestionSerializer(questions_array, many=True)
       return Response(serializer.data)
```

I alway get this error:
TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fields'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about serializing directly the QuerySet :

```
    questions  = Question.objects.filter(pk__in=[1, 4, 7])

    data = list(questions.values('id',
                              'first_field',
                              'second_field',
                              '....'
                              ))

    return JsonResponse({"data": data,}, safe=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have passed queryset in a list which is very wrong.
you can do something like:

```py
for id in ids:
    questions = Question.objects.filter(pk=id).first() #so here you will 
# get an obejct instead of queryset
    questions_array.append(questions)

serializer = QuestionSerializer(questions_array, many=True)
return Response(serializer.data)
```